# Underline instead of italic in org mode

Tags: emacs

I just switched from windows to ubuntu.
Somehow it has changed the behavior of Org mode so that now test enclosed between `/` are underlined (similarly as text enclosed between `_`) while it was italicised before.
How can I change that ?
I suppose I would have to deal with fonts and associates but I still lack proficiency in that matter.

Comment: I guess you are running Emacs inside a terminal, where there is no italics font. Try running the GUI version of emacs instead.

Comment: I run it with the GUI version.

Answer (score 5):

Move point to something that's not displayed as you want, and hit <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>.  This will bring up a new buffer with information about the character at point.

The piece you're interested in is this:

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 (italic)
```

(You might have something else than `italic` there.)

In my Emacs, `italic` is a link to a page where you can customize the face.  You can also type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `italic` directly.  In the Customize buffer that appears, you can change what the text should look like.

Comment: I followed your advice, removed the `underline` and addes `slant = italic` but now it appears just normal.
Maybe that as something to do with my font ? I noticed that the font name contains a `bold` instead of `normal` for the text enclosed between `*`. I suppose there should be an `italic` somewhere for the text enclosed between `/` but I do not now how to control that.

Comment: Hm, what's the font name?  It might be a font that doesn't have any italic form...

Comment: DéjaVu : 
`-unknown-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-`

Comment: I don't have a Linux version at hand, but it seems like DejaVu Sans Mono has a style called "oblique".  Maybe you can put in that for "slant"...

Comment: I tried every possible field in the slant customization menu (italic, `oblique`, `normal`, `italic` and `roman`) without success.

Comment: Hm, did you "apply" between each attempt?  The customize face buffer doesn't update the sample text in real time for some reason.

Comment: I used `M-x load-file` and loaded my .emacs after saving the edit page.

Comment: @AlfredM.: Did you find a solution for this by now?

Comment: @danlei: I have not this problem anymore but I don't know how. Probably some update solved it.

Comment: @AlfredM.: Ok, thanks. Then I hope it will be that way for me too. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Using a fresh installation of emacs would give me underlined text for text inside of // instead of slanted text. While using the customize-face-editor could solve the problem somehow, the solution looked messy inside my init-file and I did not understand it, which I found unpleasant. Therefore I investigated to solve the problem with "set-face-attribute". Here is what worked for me:

```
(set-face-attribute 'italic nil
                :slant 'italic 
                :underline nil)
```

Note: set-face-attribute is a function which takes a 'face and can set several :attributes with regard to the face. The "nil" is set to apply the settings to every frame.

Answer (score 0):

This answer amounts to the same thing as @legoscia's, but depending on your Emacs configuration and experience level, you may need some addition details he does not provide. For example, I am using Spacemacs with Evil mode, so <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> does not invoke the function he describes.

The function you want is `describe-text-properties` (use <kbd>SPC</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> first in Spacemacs). Follow the `(italic)` link as @legoscia describes, by placing your cursor on it and hitting enter, or using the mouse. You will then see a description of the italic face, beginning `Face: italic (sample) (customize this face)`. The `(customize this face)` part should again be a link; follow it as before. You will see something like:

[image: customize showing wrong configuration]

Note how the italic face defined in terms of underline! Click the `Show All Attributes` link, uncheck the checkbox for underline, check the checkbox for slant, and select `oblique` (or perhaps `italic`—experiment with what works for you) from the value menu. You will then need to apply and save. After clicking `Hide Unused Attributes` and `Apply and Save`, the result will look something like:

[image]

On Spacemacs, this will result in the following configuration being added to `dotspacemacs/emacs-custom-settings` (i.e. in your `.spacemacs`):

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(italic ((t (:slant oblique)))))
```

Which means the configuration should persist between sessions.

Details may depend slightly on your font; for reference, I am using Liberation Mono.